# Drop down menu but return other values in word

Tags: microsoft-word, dropdownlist

I want to make a dropdown menu in Word but when I choose something, for example "fruit" it should return as "apple".

I'm using this to create a form some kind of form for my badmintonclub (in Dutch). In the badminton competition we all have a difficult number,
so I wanna be able to (image below) choose a last name in a drop down menu in the "VBL-nummer"-tab and then the number, instead of what I choose in the dropdown menu, appears in the column "VBL-nummer".

[image]

> Little explanation of the document/image (for those who can't speak dutch ):
>
> - "Naam" ==> Last name
> - "Voornaam" ==> First name
> - "VBL-nummer" ==> The difficult number
> - "Spelers" ==> Players

You can download the document [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WUO0nxAatnKFkPTRDexHghleIlAYDd24).

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) How familiar are you with VBA?; 2) How are you populating the list?

Comment: Sure it's possible using VBA: Basically you will read the input of the player field and write the corrosponding value into the VLB-Number column. Fairly easy if you invest a little time into VBA, give it a try and let us know if you have problems (please be as specific as possible).

Comment: Keep in mind this site is not a "code writing service". You should give it a try and if you get stuck we will help you.

Comment: @Albin, and do you know how to do this or can you find an example somewhere on the internet?

Comment: @Rune I could, but that really is your job (I already told you what to look for). If you don't want to invest any time, just get a developer. This is simple, it won't cost much.

Comment: @Albin, okay. I'll try to make it work with VBA. Can I still comment here if I get stuck? Thanks!

Comment: @rune https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.dropdown shows how to add values to a list. When you select and item, word returns an index (count starts with 0). You need a way to associate the index number with the name selected. You can try an `array` of a `user-defined type` where the array is sorted in the order you have added the items to the list, and the name and VBL-number are properties of the type. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/user-defined-data-type

Comment: Sorting a random array of names is another problem you will need to solve.